# Print Random Generated Sudoku Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am having troubles printing the generated Sudoku on this program. Every time I try to print it, it says "null". Originally the code doesn't have the main method so I added one.

```java
class GenerateSudoku{
    public static int[][][] sudoku;
    public static Random rand=new Random();


    GenerateSudoku(int[][][] sudoku){
        this.sudoku=sudoku;
        for(int ctr=0; ctr<sudoku.length; ctr++){
            for(int ct=ctr; ct<sudoku.length; ct++){
                double first=rand.nextDouble(), second=rand.nextDouble();
                if(first>1-second){
                    this.sudoku[ct][ctr][0]=0;
                    this.sudoku[ct][ctr][1]=1;
                }
                else{
                    this.sudoku[ct][ctr][1]=0;
                }
                if(ct!=ctr && first>1-second){
                    this.sudoku[ctr][ct][0]=0;
                    this.sudoku[ctr][ct][1]=1;
                }
                else if(ct!=ctr){
                    this.sudoku[ctr][ct][1]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    
    public int[][][] getSudoku(){
        return sudoku;
    }
    private void sop(Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj+"");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sudoku);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your main method only executes `System.out.println(sudoku);` so of course it prints "null": the `sudoku` array is not initialized and thus `null`. You'd want to create an instance of `GenerateSudoku`, have it intialize it's _instance_ field `sudoku` (so remove the `static` keyword there and also don't pass it as an argument but actually create the array in the constructor, e.g. `sudoku = new int [9][9][2];`) and finally do something like `System.out.println(generateSudokuInstance.getSudoku())`.

Comment: @Thomas So I have to put my class inside the main method?

Comment: No, you'd want to have the class outside and you'd need to have an outer class anyway. I feel you should grab a basic Java tutorial and work through that before getting back to your own code. Things you should learn: difference between static and non-static code, encapsulation, initialization (i.e. how to initialize variables and what happens when)

Comment: @Thomas I didn't notice that, I will try on that one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you should create an instance of the `GenerateSudoku` class and get the resulting sudoku from `getSudoku()` method:

```java
import java.util.Random;

class GenerateSudoku{
    public static int[][][] sudoku;
    public static Random rand=new Random();


    GenerateSudoku(int[][][] sudoku){
        this.sudoku=sudoku;
        for(int ctr=0; ctr<sudoku.length; ctr++){
            for(int ct=ctr; ct<sudoku.length; ct++){
                double first=rand.nextDouble(), second=rand.nextDouble();
                if(first>1-second){
                    this.sudoku[ct][ctr][0]=0;
                    this.sudoku[ct][ctr][1]=1;
                }
                else{
                    this.sudoku[ct][ctr][1]=0;
                }
                if(ct!=ctr && first>1-second){
                    this.sudoku[ctr][ct][0]=0;
                    this.sudoku[ctr][ct][1]=1;
                }
                else if(ct!=ctr){
                    this.sudoku[ctr][ct][1]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    
    public int[][][] getSudoku(){
        return sudoku;
    }
    private void sop(Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj+"");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][][] sudoku = new int[9][9][2];
        GenerateSudoku generator = new GenerateSudoku(sudoku);
        sudoku = generator.getSudoku();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < sudoku.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(sudoku[i][j][1]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Generates:

```
110110011
100010111
001111100
101110010
111101111
001011100
011011000
110110000
110010001
```

Comment: Thank you so much @meowulf for this I'll try to check again on my code.